# Swift App Not Being Prompted to Upload to Fabric

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-fabric

I've been using Fabric/Crashlytics for years for my iOS and Android apps and for the most part it has worked great.

Now I'm working on some Swift apps.  I've performed the set up to get the Fabric SDK installed and configured properly.  The Fabric app confirms that all is well. Except that when I archive the app I'm never prompted to upload the app to Fabric so I can distribute it to my testers.

Anyone else run into this problem and if so how did you solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked `Ask to Distribute Archives` in Fabric App settings

Comment: Yes that option is checked and works for my objective-c based apps.